# Biasing an IC CC-CE cascade amplifier

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, ltspice, biasing

I have the following CC-CE (Common-Collector Common Emitter) cascade amplifier:

[image]

I am trying to bias the amplifier by using LTSpice. Here is my schematic below:

[image]

Apparently, from the displayed voltages, am doing something wrong. Unfortunately I can't figure out what am doing wrong, can somebody please help me by showing me how to bias the circuit properly In LTSpice??? Thank you for your help in advance.

BTW below is the dc operating point results:

[image]

Comment: That isn't a cascode amplifier.

Comment: @AndyAka, thank you for your comment, but this is what my text book calls it

Comment: It’s a cascade amplifier not cascode.

Comment: ah! your right! I will fix this shortly

Answer (score 0):

You did the same as what is in the original circuit.

**However** you're treating this amplifier as if it has a voltage output. You can treat it that way **but** you should then draw a small signal equivalent and figure out what the voltage gain will be. It will be quite large!
That means that any DC offset in the circuit will be amplified **a lot** making the output clip to its minimum or maximum voltage. That's what happens here, it clips to the minimum.

You could tune I3 such that the output vc2 is at 2.5 Volts for example but don't be surprised if you have to make the value of I3's current a very precise value. Then change the temperature (for example) and the output clips again! Hmm, that's not very useful now is it?

OK, now what if we treat the output vc2 as if a **current** comes out. So fix the voltage (at 2.5 V, use a 2.5 V DC voltage source) and observe the current through that voltage source. Now you can simulate the **small signal current gain** Iout/Iin (Iin is the current from I3).

Here's how I would simulate this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgXKzj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @Bimperlrekkie, can you elaborate more by providing a schematic that shows the biasing you mean?? I am trying to implement your biasing but am getting no luck so far. May be am doing something wrong

Comment: I added the schematic, note how I **force** the output to 2.5 V DC and **measure the current** as the output signal is a **current**. I suggest that you do a DC simulation and sweep Iin between 0 and 10 uA and observe what happens to Iout.

Comment: So I just implemented your circuit with LTSpice, I got Ib1=1.837uA, Ie1=201.94uA, Ic1=200.11uA. For Q2 I got: Ib2=1.942uA, Ic2=200.97uA. But what is confusing is that Vb2=-0.723mA, and vb1=7mV which way below the allowed threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I will propose this circuit:

[image]

It should give you the correct results in AC analysis from 10Hz to 100KHz.

Or you can try this way also:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Would you please elaborate on why you connected the emitter of Q3 to -5V, and please explain how does the circuit on the far right works? This is a very ingenious technique and would like to explore it. Again, thank you very much

Comment: The negative supply voltage is not needed. E1 is a voltage controlled voltage source and he is used as an op-amp in integrator configuration. It provides a large negative feedback around the circuit to stabilize the DC-bias point at 2.5V.

Comment: Oh wow! That is advanced, am not near that stage yet. It is interesting how my book presented this problem with no information on how to bias the circuit, yet now I look at your answer and it contains advanced solution. Do you think there is a simpler solution to this problem, because in the end I want to bias the circuit correctly so I can find the input resistance

Comment: I updated my answer. Is the method is simpler? Also, for your circuit finding Rin is a trivial task. Do you know the Rin for CE amplifier with emitter degeneration resistor?

Comment: My theoretical calculations say Rin=rpi1+(beta+1)rpi2. Is that correct?

Comment: Almost right. You simply forgot about ro1.

Comment: You know, I included it in my circuit analysis but the mathematics wasn't working out, any suggestions?

Comment: Very strange because ro1 is connected between Q1 emitter and ground (for AC signals).  And Q1 emitter is connected to the Q2 base so it should be obvious to you that ro1 is in parallel with rpi2.

Comment: Ah! I think your mentioning that using the hybrid-pi model. I use the T-model which is kinda confusing

Comment: You mast made a mistake somewhere because T-mode should give you the same answer as pi-model.

Comment: Yes, I will go ahead recheck my answer. Thank you VERY MUCH for your CLEAR and PERCISE answer. You are a big help!

Comment: Glad to see the negative-feedback biasing.